# Can one prescribe both the scalar curvature and the metric, in the Einstein-Hilbert action?

Tags: metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry

I am trying to understand what are the independent inputs to the Hilbert-Einstein action:

$$
I=\frac{1}{2\kappa} \iiiint R\sqrt{-g} d^4x
$$

In some sources, I am lead to believe that $R$ is any smooth real-valued function, and elsewhere that it is dependent on the metric or other quantities, so I am confused about their independence.

Can I prescribe $R$ to be any arbitrary smooth function $R:\mathcal{M}\to \mathbb{R}$, and $g$ to be any arbitrary metric $g:T_p M \times T_pM \to \mathbb{R}$? Or, is $R$ implicitly dependent upon $g$ such that prescribing $g$ fixes $R$?

Do any prescription of $R$ and $g$ form a valid Hilbert-Einstein action?

Comment: In general, when $R$ is a smooth function on a riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, $R$ means the scalar curvature of $g$. It is defined to be the trace of the Ricci tensor, which depends on $g$. Here ,the formula is just the integral of the scalar curvature with respect to the (pseudo-)riemannian volume form.

Comment: In the Einstein-Hilbert action $R$ is the scalar curvature. I'm don't really know if that is what you're asking - if you want to dream up another action you can take $R$ to be something different. In particular you could take $R$ to be some _fixed_ function on $M$, but then you will not find any stationary $g$ for the functional (in that case you can always make $I$ smaller or larger my multiplying $g$ with a constant for example - or by moving volume to places where $R$ is small or large if you want to keep the volume of $g$ fixed).

Comment: @DIdier_ So the only prescribed quantity is the metric?

Comment: @DIdier_ actually, one can either prescribe the metric or the scalar curvature since prescribing either fixes the other.

Comment: @AlexandreH.Tremblay Depends on the manifold. For some manifolds, you cannot find any metric with positive scalar curvature. See Gromov-Lawson's theorem for example. This is a hard (and very interesting) question to find what fuction can be the scalar curvature of a fixed manifold.

Comment: An action is a *functional*, that is, it takes as an input a function and returns a real number. To define the Einstein-Hilbert action, one must also specify its domain. Usually (for the Vacuum case) it is defined to be a function of the metric $g$, and so $R$ would also implicitly be a function of $g$.